# Cannot make USSD calls with symbols * # in iOS 15.4

Tags: ios, swift, ussd

Up until iOS 15.3 users were able to make USSD calls from within my app, considering USSD calls include symbols * and #, but as of 15.4 that seems to no longer be the case.

I haven't come across any other question addressing this issue here on SO, but there is a discussion about it here: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/701865

Does anybody know if Apple have removed the ability for users to make USSD calls containing * and #, ie.

```swift
URL(string: "tel://*123#")
```

since that feature have been a bit frowned upon earlier, but has still worked?

"... Specifically, if a URL contains the * or # characters, the Phone app does not attempt to dial the corresponding phone number", Apple docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899-CH6-SW1

This is a really crucial part of my app. Is there any workaround?

Comment: From the Apple forum post you linked to: "iOS 15.4 seems never allow USSD number for security reason[s]." However, one of the replies there suggests it does work if you use a web view, and another suggests you need to percent-encode the `#` and `*` characters. Have you tried either of those solutions?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, however (as it also says further down in the discussion) percent encoding doesn't work.

WebView is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just downloaded iOS 15.5 beta 4 and the issue seems to have been fixed.

Update from user21 answer here: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/701865

Link to download iOS 15.5 beta 4 here: https://developer.apple.com/download/